# jQuery slide up on click is not working

Tags: jquery, html, image, click, slider

I'm tring to slide the pictures up when user clicks inside the div.
This is not working only slideup without display the next image.

I also want it to slide up back to the top when last image is clicked (or slide down back to the first image)

Any idea ?

CSS:

```
#clickbox {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

html :

```
<div id="clickbox">
    <img src="http://socialmediaseo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/500px-android-logosvg-300x300.png" width="300" height="300">
    <img src="http://www.backwoodshome.com/blogs/ClaireWolfe/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/CopBashingMedicalPatient-300x300.jpg" width="300" height="300">
    <img src="http://www.prieteni.ro/uploads/albumfoto/396711_353820_wy_s_300x300.gif" width="300" height="300">
    <img src="http://f1.pepst.com/c/EBF8DC/25835/ssc3/home/023/deepakjain/albums/face_13.1kb.jpg_480_480_0_64000_0_1_0.jpg" width="300" height="300">       
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $( "#clickbox" ).on( "click", function() {
        $( "#clickbox" ).slideUp( 2000 );
    });
```

the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9CpxX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$( "#clickbox" ).slideUp( 2000 );
```

with

```
if ($( this ).find("img:visible").length > 1)
$( this ).find("img:visible").first().slideUp( 2000 );
else
$( this ).find("img:not(visible)").slideDown(2000);
```

**EDIT**

Put the images inside divs for each and then do

```
if ($( this ).find("div:visible").length > 1)
$( this ).find("div:visible").first().slideUp( 2000 );
else
$( this ).find("div:not(visible)").slideDown(2000);
```

It looks a lot better